# iOS: Not able to navigate to another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a main view controller in which I have a UITableView. And in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath(), I am initializing a new view controller and trying to navigate to it. Below is my code. But I am unable to go to the other view controller.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SubViewController *subView = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    [subView setData:[[sources getSubCategories] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:subView animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: can you tried my answer..

Comment: Why do you init `SubViewController` without nib?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Adding Go through the initwith Nibname...

```
SubViewController *subView = [[SubViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubViewController" bundle:Nil];

    // Puishing a view controller in naviogation bar.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:subView animated:YES];
```

Try this one might be helpful to you...